# SSL Certificate Implementation

Tags: authentication, ssl, microservices

I have 3 microservices MS1, MS2 and MS3 out of which 2 microservice needs SSL Certificate authentication between MS2 and MS3 and MS1 should interact with MS2 without SSL Certificates.
But after implementing SSL in MS2 (using tomcat as base docker image), I am not able to access Endpoints in MS2 from MS1 and getting HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error.

Is it mandatory to configure SSL in MS1 also?

MS1 should be able to access endpoints in MS2 without any issue.

Comment: HTTP status not found has nothing to do with TLS, which is applied *before* HTTP. Generally you'd use a specific port for TLS traffic (e.g. 443 for HTTPS instead of port 80 for plain HTTP) or you'd use options such as STARTTLS. But sorry, first of all we cannot debug from a distance, and secondly this is not about programming, it's about server configuration.